# Building a concise, scalable CSS library using CSS transforms

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors, scalability, css-transforms

In an attempt to build a scalable CSS library for SVGs I have looked into CSS Attribute Selectors to handle common CSS transform animations.

You can easily take an SVG `.__svg { width: 1em; height: 1em; }` and modify it concisely with `.__svg[class*="--large"] { transform: scale(1.5); }` Can you see the issue I am facing already?
While this allows for an efficient use of both `<svg class="__svg" />` and `<svg class="__svg--large" />` it makes it impossible to have multiple, chained transforms, as one transform will override the other.

```
.__svg[class*="--large"] { transform: scale(1.5); }
.__svg[class*="--rotate"] { transform: rotate(90deg); }
```

An `<svg class="__svg--large--rotate" />` only rotates, and does not scale.

So then, I can only take advantage of performant transform paints for one value. Enter SASS and fixins to generate the library for me; but now the intent to keep the CSS library concise is completely dissolved.

```
.__svg[class*="--large"] { transform: scale(1.5); }
.__svg[class*="--rotate"] { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.__svg[class*="--large--rotate"] { transform: scale(1.5) rotate(90deg); }
```

In so many ways I wish any chainable CSS values harnessed a spread operator like JS's.
How would you build a CSS library of commonly used selectors and keep selectors to a minimum?

Comment: don't think you can for transforms due to them overriding each other, as you have found out, you would need to program each combination needed separately

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible without using javascript.

But it's absolutely possible with a pinch of javascript.

**Working Example:**

```js
// Build an object of all the transforms
const svgTransforms = {

  '--large' : 'scale(1.5)',
  '--rotate' : 'rotate(90deg)'
}

// Build an array of all the transform names
const svgTransformNames = Object.keys(svgTransforms);

// Add transforms to each SVG element, according to classList
let svgElements = [... document.getElementsByClassName('__svg')];

for (let svgElement of svgElements) {

  let svgElementTransforms = [];

  for (let svgTransformName of svgTransformNames) {

    if (svgElement.classList.contains(svgTransformName)) {

      svgElementTransforms.push(svgTransforms[svgTransformName]);
    }
  }
  
  svgElement.style.transform = svgElementTransforms.join(' ');
}
```

```css
.__svg {
display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 60px;
margin: 24px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="__svg --large"></div>
<div class="__svg --rotate"></div>
<div class="__svg --large --rotate"></div>
```